# How to do a cascade save in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, save, cascade

I have objects A and B.

Object A is like

```
class A{
 Set<B>
}
```

Now when I save A I want that all objects in `Set<B>` of A should be automatically saved in DB. How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
// Use the cascade option in your annotation
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<FieldEntity> getB() {
    return fields;
}
```

Comment: How can i do it using hbm files?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Answer (score 2):

The question from Ransom will work if you are working through EntityManager and using pure JPA annotations. But if you are using Hibernate directly, then you need to use its own annotation for cascading.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

...

@OneToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
public List<FieldEntity> getB() {
    return fields;
}
```